# BTrDB Failure to connect

Tags: database, go, time-series

I have a copy of the BTrDB container running on my VM and a Go program that's trying to test it by taking data from a CSV and inserting it. Unfortunately, I get errors when trying to connect

```
ctx, _ := context.WithDeadline(context.TODO(), time.Now().Add(time.Duration(30)*time.Second))
_, err := btrdb.Connect(ctx, "192.168.99.100:4410")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Unexpected connection error: %v", err)
}
```

yields

> 2017/03/14 14:09:17 transport: http2Client.notifyError got notified that the client transport was broken read tcp 192.168.99.1:54212->192.168.99.100:4410: read: connection reset by peer.
>   2017/03/14 14:09:17 Unexpected connection error: %vCould not connect to cluster via provided endpoints
>   attempt to obtain MASH from 192.168.99.100:4410 yielded rpc error: code = Internal desc = transport is closing

I have the container installed per the instructions on the GitHub page, with a few modifications

```
docker network create mynet
docker run -d --net mynet --name btrmongo mongo:3.2
docker run -it --net mynet -v /Users/keithnordstrom/btrdata:/srv -e BTRDB_MONGO_SERVER=btrmongo.mynet btrdb/release:3.4 makedb
docker run -d --name btrdb --net mynet -v /Users/keithnordstrom/btrdata:/srv -p 4410:4410 -e BTRDB_MONGO_SERVER=btrmongo.mynet btrdb/release:3.4
```

Here's a concurrent sample of the log from the BTrDB side

> 2017/03/14 20:08:28 main.go:114 ▶ Still alive
>   2017/03/14 20:08:28 blockcache.go:20 ▶ Cachestats: 0 misses, 0 hits, NaN %
>   2017/03/14 20:08:28 main.go:47 ▶ Num goroutines: 16
>   2017/03/14 20:08:29 main.go:47 ▶ Num goroutines: 16
>   2017/03/14 20:08:30 main.go:47 ▶ Num goroutines: 16
>   2017/03/14 20:08:31 main.go:47 ▶ Num goroutines: 16
>   2017/03/14 20:08:32 cpinterface.go:59 ▶ cpnp connection
>   2017/03/14 20:08:32 cpinterface.go:64 ▶ ERR (%v) :: %v 192.168.99.1:54212 capn: too much data in stream
>   2017/03/14 20:08:32 cpinterface.go:59 ▶ cpnp connection
>   2017/03/14 20:08:32 cpinterface.go:64 ▶ ERR (%v) :: %v 192.168.99.1:54213 EOF
>   2017/03/14 20:08:32 main.go:47 ▶ Num goroutines: 16
>   2017/03/14 20:08:33 main.go:114 ▶ Still alive

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are using the v3 server container with the v4 binding libraries.

It is definitely recommended to use v4, so you can try setting up the v4 stack by following the guide at [smartgrid.store](https://docs.smartgrid.store)

That stack assumes you are using kubernetes and ceph, but you can also set up a development deployment using minikube and no ceph, although the documentation is a little thinner there.

To get faster responses, you can also email btrdb@googlegroups.com

EDIT: it does seem like the out of date readme led you astray. I'll update that now. Thanks

Comment: I wondered if something that might be the case. And yes, the docs on your github did make it seem like the go bindings would work with the 3.4 distro. Thanks for updating.

I just looked over your docs on smart grid. Is there a way to install a single node container without ceph, kubernetes, etc.? Our stack takes up a lot of room on my local VM and right now I’m more interested in testing software integrations with your API in as simple an environment as possible.